# adding chat functonality into a basic rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, web-applications, chat

I have a basic rails app in which users can sign in and add friends. I want to add the ability for a signed in user to chat with a friend of theirs. 
The app isn't meant for production so I am looking for something simple and easy to implement. I tried integrating an already made [pusher chat app](https://github.com/tarnfeld/PusherChat-Rails) from github into my app but can't seem to get it to work. Is there an easy way out?

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

gem '[private_pub](http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye)'

See this video and apply that steps

http://railscasts.com/episodes/316-private-pub

**Update** - One more solution

See Video of Messaging with Faye - [Railscast 260](http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye).

Comment: It doesn't work on windows. Getting ` sys/socket.h: No such file or directory` when I run bundle install. And then when I run `rails g private_pub:install`, it says `Could not find hiredis-0.3.2 in any of the sources` So, how do I run it on windows?

Comment: I tried running that private_pub app (screencast #316) on ubuntu and got this error : `axconfig: port 1 not active
axconfig: port 2 not active`. So, How should I run the app?

Comment: I guess that was probably because I hadn't installed nodejs.

Comment: Every time I run the app, the faye server shuts down dues to `segmentation fault`. and the chrome console gives this error `Failed to load resource: http://localhost:9292/faye.js ` Any idea why?